# strange behaviour of a p element

Tags: html, css

Hi what's wrong with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ciroxxx/PJenJ/72/)

The problem is in these lines:

```
<p>
    <span class="is_not_active">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </span>                 
</p>
```

If take away the p element I can see the red arrow, otherwise the arrow is invisibile. Can you tell me something. Try yourself with the fiddle.
Thanks

Comment: If you switch the p to a div you can see the arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a `<div>` inside a `<p>` and get consistent results from various browsers. Provide the browsers with valid HTML and they would behave uniformly.

You can put `<div>` inside a `<div>` though so if you replace your `<p>` with `<div class="name">` and style it appropriately, you can get what you want.

```
<div>
    <span class="is_not_active">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </span>                 
</div>
```

This would work. I modified your fiddle and tested.

Answer (score 0):

`<P>` tags aren't allowed to contain anything but inline elements according to [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html).

`<DIV>`s are block element.